# Xamarin.iOS status bar becomes default when app on (Task Manager)/App Switcher

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an issue on iOS when switching apps. The status bar color changes to default , does anyone knows how to fix this? Seems like it's a bug on iOS itself.

**Note:** I am not using a `Navigation Bar` in this case.

So far I only have this service in iOS whenever I want to change the status bar color.

```
public void ChangeStatusBarEffects(Color StatusBarColor, bool IsDarkTheme = false)
{
    if (IsDarkTheme)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, false);
            UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
            if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
            {
               statusBar.BackgroundColor = StatusBarColor.ToUIColor();
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.BlackOpaque, false);
            UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
            if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
            {
                statusBar.BackgroundColor = StatusBarColor.ToUIColor();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: A screenshot showing the iOS app switcher with the OPs app having a white navigation bar.]

Comment: How are you changing the navigation bar color?

Comment: @G.hakim I've added the code

Comment: You know you are marking the Navigation bar and showing me the code for status bar right?

Comment: @G.hakim Erm yes, I tried NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = StatusBarColor.ToUIColor(); and insert it in my current code which is the above one, and it didn't worked.

Comment: You seem to be using `Xamarin.Forms` and then making changes in native now if you would have done something cross-platform that will override your previous change.

Comment: @G.hakim  The default color which is the white one was set on Info.plist. So I am calling the service whenever I want to change the status bar color, thus as you have said, this should override the change.

Comment: If you trying to change the navigation bar colour I would suggest you use the Xamarin Forms API `BarBackgroundColor` on your Navigation page instance something like this:   `var navPage= new NavigationPage(page);
            navPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0082C6");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189245/discussion-between-swift-talt-and-g-hakim).

Comment: Have you found  solution to this problem already?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way around this.

I have added a view with the colour that I want to appear when the app is the task manager view. This view is in between the main view and the safe area.

This view will be underneath the system bar, however when the app goes to the task manager (or app switch screen) then the view becomes visible.

Might have a better way around this but this is the only way I got this to work!